# Disable <0:p> in Outlook Email

Tags: css, outlook, html-email, vml

Outlook automatically adds tags to an email. I have a tiny gap I am attempting to remove. It looks like I have the following code: `<o:p>&nbsp;</o:p>`.

I'd like to hide the tag by creating a css style to hide it.

Comment: This is the tag after the interpretation by outlook. Maybe provide the code from before sending the email.

Comment: What system is used to sent the html with?